# Mandelbrot in python

Tags: python, mandelbrot

I am trying to code a Mandelbrot set in python. But my code shows a black image instead of the Mandelbrot image. This is my full code.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def mandelbrot_count(c,n):
    z = 0j
    for i in range(n):
        z = z*z+c
        if abs(z)>2:
            return i
    return n


width = 300
height = 300

image_array = np.zeros((height,width))

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        c = complex(i,j)
        n = mandelbrot_count(c,30)
        image_array[i][j]=n

image = Image.fromarray(image_array)
image.show()
```

Comment: You have to rescale - the interesting dynamics for the Mandelbrot set happen for i between -2 and 2  and j between -1 and +1.

Comment: @Eka here is nice example: https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/auto_examples/plot_mandelbrot.html

Answer (score 3):

as mentioned: rescaling. For example range -2.25 to 0.75 and -1.25 to 1.25 with > 1000 steps brings you the attached image.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def mandelbrot_count(c,n):
    z = 0j
    for i in range(n):
        z = z*z+c
        if abs(z)>2:
            return i
    return n

width = 1500
height = 1250

image_array = np.zeros((height,width))

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        c = complex(-2.25+i*(0.75+2.25)/1500,-1.25 + j*(1.25 + 1.25)/1250)
        n = mandelbrot_count(c,30)
        image_array[i][j]=n

image = Image.fromarray(image_array)
image.show()
```

[image]